# Open a page above another page in react like we open a post in reddit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, popup, reddit

I want to open posts from a feed like how Reddit does it. When you open a post on Reddit it opens above the previous page so after closing or going back the feed stays as it was.
I am using ReactJS.

Comment: Look up Modals.

Answer (score 0):

Check [React Bootstrap Modals](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/), this is what you're asking for.
Just add the react bootstrap package to your project and customize your modal the way you want. Enjoy!

Comment: I was asking for URL-based modals.